# Pulling a generic list with AutoID from Firebase with Kotlin

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am fetching data generically via Firebase. But I'm having trouble when I try to pull a list with an autoId. My network layer is below;

My fetch request similar;
What I need are item objects.

```
{
   id: xxx
       item: yyyy
   id: xxx
       item: yyyy
   id: xxx
       item: yyyy
   id: xxx
       item: yyyy
}
```

Sealed Class

```
sealed class FDBReadService<T: Any>: FDBNetworkReadService<T> {
    data class getQuestion(val persistent: Int, val forLesson: String): FDBReadService<ArrayList<Question>>()
```

interfaces

```
    interface FDBTargetReadType<T: Any>: FDBTargetType {
    var database: DatabaseReference
    fun provideBaseURL(): FDBBaseURL
    fun providePath(): String
    fun provideAutoID(): Boolean
}
```

Network Action

```
@Throws(BaseError::class)
suspend inline fun <reified T : Any> FDBNetworkReadService<T>.execute(): T {
    val snapshot = database.child(provideBaseURL().path + providePath()).get().await()
    if (provideAutoID()) {
        val values = snapshot.children.map {
            it.value
        }
        val gsonValue = Gson().toJson(values)
        val listItem = Gson().fromJson(gsonValue, T::class.java)

        //val item = values as T
        return  listItem
    }

    val responseModel = snapshot.getValue(T::class.java)

    if (responseModel != null) {
        return responseModel
    } else {
        throw BaseError.databaseError()
    }

}
```

When I try to convert the list I received into json and then convert it into an object, it doesn't work. When I cast the 'values' value with T, I see objects in the list that I do not want in the incoming data, and it crashes when I try to access any object.

Comment: When an app crashes, it writes an error message and stack trace to its logcat. Please find those, and add them to your question by clicking the `edit` link under it. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.